# Elastic load balancer for Kafka rest proxy on SASL_SSL cluster

Tags: amazon-elb, confluent-platform, kafka-rest, confluent-rest-proxy

I am trying to configure Elastic Load Balancer on AWS to work with Confluent Kafka Rest Proxy servers. The Kafka cluster is SASL_SSL ( SASL is Kerberos) with ACL enabled. While configuring ELB listener's target I get "unhealthy" error ( error code 502). I don't see any error code on Broker (authorizer log) or Rest proxy log.  If I use ELB's target rest proxies on a cluster which is plaintext it works. What is the reason for the error ?